# How do I set autogeneration for a PK column using EF Core's fluent syntax?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to mark my `Id` property as the PK, which is auto-generated and auto-incremented.

In EF6 I would do this:

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Foo>()
  .HasKey(m => m.MyPkColumn);

modelBuilder
  .Entity<Foo>()
  .Property(m => m.MyPkColumn)
  .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);   // this doesn't work
```

This doesn't work in EF Core. What is the new syntax?

Comment: If you name the key property "Id", and make it an `int` type, it will automatically be configured as an Identity type in SQL Server. There is no need to configure it at all.

Comment: @MikeBrind I don't like conventions. I want to be able to specify it as I've been able to in EF6. Is it possible in EF7/Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core has a new method: `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` which replaces the `DatabaseGeneratedOptions` from EF 6:

`modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(p => p.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();`

Comment: Thanks for that. Though [the docs say](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/generated-properties.html#value-generated-on-add-fluent-api) that it does not guarantee that the value will be generated. And then that "it depends" on the DBMS. So basically, the new way is more confusing, and does less. Unless there is another solution.

Comment: @grokky The idea in EF Core is that you can setup it differently for each database provider. If you are using SqlServer, the direct equivalent is `UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()` method.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah I noticed that, but we need the same data layer code deployed on both MSSQL and SQLite or something similar (server and mobile client). Pity there is no default like before.

Comment: It seems to me that `ValueGeneratedOnAdd`is no different to using `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. Both approaches rely on the provider to implement it as an autoincremented, autogenerated value. So in that regard, it is just like "before".

Comment: That's very interesting... I didn't realise that EF6 relied on the DBMS when using `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`. I used it on various DBMS' and it always worked as expected. Curious. Anyways, even if that's the case, I never needed to encode the fact that I'm using DBMS "x" before, now I need to.